What is the difference between public and private RSA keys?
I have been learning about generating RSA keys and am wondering if there is a particular reason why the private key is the private key and the public the public. As far as I know the encryption is bi-directional so either key can encrypt messages which can only be decrypted by the other. So what determines which key is labelled as 'public'?
Could someone not generate a pair and give out the 'private' key while never sharing the public and have the whole system work the same way but in reverse? Or am I missing something

Also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29030/18298 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/112026/18298


Could someone not generate a pair and give out the 'private' key while never sharing the public and have the whole system work the same way but in reverse?

Well, no.  Actually, we could generate a pair of keys which are essentially equivalent, and arbitrarily label one private and one public, but we would end up with a rather more expensive system.  What we do in practice is perform some optimizations to both the public and private key; these optimizations would make giving out the private key insecure.
Here are some of these optimizations:

For the public key, we usually make the exponent small.  We can do that because, since it's public, we don't mind if it's guessable, and making it small makes the public operations go much faster.  Now, it would obviously be bad if we kept that as the private key - if someone just guessed the private exponent, all security would be lost (and there are subtler attacks that work if the private exponent is somewhat larger).

For the private key, we don't care if someone can deduce the factorization from it.  So, what we do is generate some additional parameters that allow us to implement the 'CRT' optimization; this gives a perhaps 4x speed up of the private operation (which isn't bad).  However, these additional parameters include the values of p and q - obviously, we wouldn't want to publish those in our public key.


